# use StucturedTextEditor for custom IEditorInput

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My task is to develop multipage editor for xml-based content with source page.
The result have to be like platform development editor for platform.xml file.

The editing content is not file based. I have EditorInput class which has the object for edit.

I found that standard Xml editor from Web tool platform use StructuredTextEditor class for Source tab.

```
    public class MyEditor extends FormEditor
    {

       ...

       protected void addPages()
       {
          try
          {
            MyFirstPage pgFirst = new MyFirstPage(...);
            addPage(pgFirst);

            StructuredTextEditor pgEditor = new StructuredTextEditor();
            addPage(pgEditor, getEditorInput());
          }
          catch (PartException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }

      ...
}
```

Problem: i need good tutorial for use StructuredTextEditor(what dependecies i need, how can i use my IEditorInput implementation for StructuredTextEditor document source).

Is StructuredTextEditor is a good choise for xml source editor widget?

Comment: If you mean `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor` that is part of Eclipse WST so you will drag in a lot of additional WST code if you use this.

Comment: Not as much as you might think for that (*sigh* EMF), but the XML language support will in order to support using DTDs and XSDs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on what features you need. You can actually can start from TextEditor as well.

I can't tell about XML Editor from WTP that may have a lot of dependencies and uses cases, but there is nice open source [Rinzo XML Editor](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rinzo-xml-editor)

Sources are at https://github.com/ccancinos/rinzo-xml-editor

So as user try to find the XML Editor that you like and is as close as possible to what you need. Than search for its sources.
Sometimes it is too complicated, then consider option 2 ...

It is up to you.